# Notification in gingerbread

Tags: android

Hi guys i want try to show notification in android 2.3.x but doesn't work.
In Android 4.x this work fine...
there is a logcat:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/7648767/

code:

```
protected void ShowNotification(int icon ,String title, String text){
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(text)
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // requires VIBRATE permission
        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
        .bigText(text));

    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(incMyNum(), mBuilder.build());
    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager
        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
    mBuilder.build();
}
```

in logcat:

```
06-15 16:20:53.989: E/AndroidRuntime(451):  at com...........ShowNotification(DettagliVolo.java:639)
```

is this:

```
notificationManager.notify(incMyNum(), mBuilder.build());
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

In emulator with GB crash... and if i run my application in a emulator with ICS+ work fine!
There is a solution? Thank you!

2.Question: is possible show notification default in big mode? (expanded)

Comment: Please post full `LogCat`.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7648767/

Comment: possible duplicate of [NotificationManager crashes only in Device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654414/notificationmanager-crashes-only-in-device)

Comment: But in my Galaxy S3 it work fine.. doesn't work only in gingerbread emulator

Comment: That phone isn't GB. Please check out that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supplying a `PendingIntent` as content Intent (to be executed when the notification is clicked) is mandatory for some Android versions.

Provide one (at least opening your app's main Activity) with [`mBuilder.setContentintent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentIntent%28android.app.PendingIntent%29).

Comment: Ok, I do not want open MainActivity or other class with intent.. is possible a fake click?

Comment: A `PendingIntent` can also send a broadcast or call a service. Use any of those options.